# SQL, MDX, Join the result of 2 queries into one

Tags: mdx

Using SQL Server 2014 SSAS. 
I need help creating one query from the 2 following MDX queries.

I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [ItemType].[ItemType Key].&[Large Bag]}on columns,
    NON EMPTY { ([MainMarket].[MainMarket Key].&[BOSTON] ) } ON ROWS
    FROM [Cube1];
```

Returns:

```
          Large Bag
BOSTON      24,911 

SELECT NON EMPTY {[ItemCategory].[ItemCategory Desc].&[Dress Item]} on columns,
    NON EMPTY { [MainMarket].[MainMarket Key].&[BOSTON]  ) } ON ROWS
    FROM [Cube1];
```

Returns:

```
        Dress Item
BOSTON  519,699
```

I need to return:

```
            Large Bag   Dress Item
BOSTON      24,911      519,699
```

Thanks for any help.

Note

I need one query that will put the dimensions side by side as column headings with the sum on the rows.

ItemType and ItemCategory are dimensions as well as MainMarket. I want the ItemType and ItemCategory as columns (next to each other, not one on top of the other) and the MainMarkets as rows.

In this example, I get all the ItemsTypes as column headers with the states as rows with each related total sum for each state/Item. I can run the same query replacing the ItemType dimension with the ItemCategory dimension and obtain the same result.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[ItemType].[ItemType Key].ALLMEMBERS} on columns,
    NON EMPTY {[MainMarket].[MainMarket Key].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
    FROM [Cube1];
```

What I need is a query that will return both Item dimensions as columns side by side;

```
         Type1   Type2  Type3   Category1   Category2   Category3
Albany    100     200    700        250       250         500
Boston    100     350    300        250       250         250
Chicago    10      20     80         50        50           0
```

Comment: The display is not correct. I need the dimensions to be on columns next to each other

Comment: Can you please amend the question so we know exactly what is required?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first past of your question only, the two queries you give can be combined using a comma to list two members in the first set:

```
SELECT 
{[ItemType].[ItemType Key].&[Large Bag],[ItemCategory].[ItemCategory Desc].&[Dress Item]} ON COLUMNS,
{[MainMarket].[MainMarket Key].&[BOSTON]} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube1];
```

Note that the numbers displayed will be from the default measure. You can specifiy which measure you want to see using `WHERE ([Measures].[NameOfMeasure])` on the end of the query.